# Switch with multiple different instances into a class

Tags: c#

I have some classes,

```
public abstract class Event{
}

public class EventA : Event{
   public string Id{get; private set;}
   public string Name{get; private set;}
   public EventA(string id, string name){
     Id = id;
     Name = name;
   }
} 

public class EventB : Event{
   public string Prop{get; private set;}
   public string Prop1{get; private set;}
   public EventA(string prop, string prop1){
     Prop = prop;
     Prop1 = prop1;
   }
}

public class EventC : Event{
   // .........
}  

public class EventD : Event{
   // .........
}  

public class SomeClass{
    public Event SomeMethod(){
       switch(SomeCondition){
          case "FirstCondition":
                return new EventA(...);
          case "SecondCondition":
                return new EventC(...); 
          case "ThirdCondition":
                return new EventC(...);
          case "FourthCondition":
                return new EventD(...);

       }
    }
}
```

Now I have 2 questions,

1) Event class should be interface or abstract class here?

2) How to move switch statement into a class that makes more sense. Should I use a Factory here or is there any design pattern I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with an interface is never a bad idea because many design patterns are based on them, e.g., if you want to implement IoC or a factory.

So event could become IEvent:

```
public interface IEvent
{
}
```

Now, let's say all your events must be initialized in a certain way or they should share some common basic implementation, then you could use an abstract class which all the event implementations will inherit from:

```
public abstract BaseEvent : IEvent
{
     protected BaseEvent(string name);

     //Method must be implemented
     public abstract SomeMethod();

     //Method can be overriden
     public virtual DoSomething()
     {
     }
}
```

Then, you can create your actual "Event" implementations, all sharing a common interface and some basic functionality which you can modify using polymorphism, for example:

```
public EventA : BaseEvent
{
    public EventA() : base("Event A")
    {
    }

    public override SomeMethod()
    {
    }

    public override DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

Finally, to answer your question, how would you initialize your objects?

That really depends of what you need for your application, will this implementation often change? Do you need a layer of abstraction that will allow you to replace the whole implementation for a newer or different technology at a latter time (for example a new database system), is it a big project with different teams involved?

For a simple system that will never change you could do something like you are already doing, for a more complex system you can use an IoC container, the factory pattern as you suggest in your question or a combination of both, here is a simple implementation of the factory pattern:

```
public interface IEventFactory
{
    IEvent CreateEvent(string someCondition);
}

public class EventFactory : IEventFactory
{
    public IEvent CreateEvent(string someCondition)
    {
        switch(SomeCondition){
            case "FirstCondition":
                return new EventA();
            case "SecondCondition":
                return new EventB(); 
            case "ThirdCondition":
                return new EventC();
            case "FourthCondition":
                return new EventD();
    }
}
```

To use the factory, you could register it using a dependency injection container (e.g. [Unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer)), here is a very simple example:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IEventFactory, EventFactory >();
```

And every time you need to get the factory:

```
var eventFactory = container.Resolve<IEventFactory>();

var someEvent = eventFactory.CreateEvent("SomeCondition");
```

Of course, although this design makes a lot of sense for things like a database abstraction layer, it might be overkill for your event system.

Answer (score 3):

In short, an `interface` shares *contract* between implementers, an `abstract class` shares contract and *implementation* between inheritors.

Due to constrains of the language, you can only inherit from one single class, so you should only use abstract classes when you need them, in case users need to inherit from another class *and* fulfill your contract.

It seems you have no implementation here, so an interface would be the better choice.

I don't really get your second question. Yes, encapsulating your switch in a class would be called a factory pattern and not uncommon. But it seems you already *did* that. So... nothing to do there.